# Amazon Selling Partner API - How to get info about Refunds / Returns (Fulfillment by Amazon)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm successfully using the [Amazon Selling Partner API](https://github.com/amz-tools/amazon-sp-api) to retrieve orders and order details that were last updated during a given time period. The challenge I am faced with now is determining whether a given order was returned and/or refunded. These orders, for what it's worth, are all FBA (Fulfillment by Amazon). I'm having trouble figuring out which API endpoints might give me that information. It's a bit surprising to me that the Order records don't seem to become updated when an order is returned (or at least I don't see how to tell).

Which API call do you make to find out what Orders / Line Items were Returned and/or Refunded during a given time period?

Alternatively, which API call do you make to find out if an Order / Line Items was Returned and/or Refunded?

Alternatively, where in an Order record (as retrieved by what set of API calls) do you look to determine whether an Order / Line Item was Returned and/or Refunded?

Comment: From searching through the repo you linked to, I think you should be able to use the Finances API with `GET /finances/v0/orders/{orderId}/financialEvents`  to get refund events. See an [example usage here](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/1846). As for returns, I only see [this report](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/a7ec0b2c68/references/reports-api/reporttype-values.md#fulfillment-by-amazon-fba-reports), but don't know if it's relevant. Anyway, let me know if it helps and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Hi. Were you able to find a solution? Thanks

Comment: @mbx Sadly I was not...  :(